# Marketing Cloud - Default Lead Capture Data Extension Fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, leads, facebook, ad-studio

I'm unable to setup Facebook lead ads in our client's account since I don't have access to it but I need to review what data is captured by default in Salesforce Marketing Cloud and any additional fields they want. I've been digging into SF docs but couldn't find any documentation on the default fields that are captured from FB lead ads. I've only been able to get a few fields from a screenshot in this [article](https://dare2mull.wordpress.com/2019/02/13/capturing-facebook-leads-into-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).

Can anyone provide a full list of default fields created by SFMC Ad Studio when setting up a Lead Capture Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bare minimum fields are these ones here:

- Lead ID
- Lead Gen Form ID
- Facebook Page ID
- Facebook Ad ID
- Facebook Ad Name
- Facebook Ad Set ID
- Facebook Ad Set Name
- Facebook Campaign ID
- Facebook Campaign Name
- Facebook Platform
- Date Collected

With a sample set here:
[image]

I did only use Lead Ads Testing Tool in FB, hence the lack of  ad and campaign related parameters.
Anything beyond the fields listed above (e.g. email, first_name, last_name) is for you to select when creating the lead form, along with additional questions not fetching data directly from lead's Facebook profile.

Be aware to not use the data extension as a sendable one, if your subscriber key is different from email address (which it should be).

Comment: Thank you, Lukas!

Comment: You're welcome, Zack